# PHP How to avoid duplicate entry of session variables in form

Tags: php, facebook, session

I'm Using , Login with facebook functionality in my form. I'm storing user data in session variable like

**1. User name and email Retrieved from facebook**

```
$userdata = $facebook->api('/me');
    $_SESSION['username'] = $userdata['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $userdata['email'];

            header("Location: register.php?source=fb");
```

**2. Session variable used in registration form**

```
    $fbusername =  $_SESSION['username'];
     $fbemail=$_SESSION['email'];
     $source = $_REQUEST['source'];

 <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if($source=='fb'){ echo  $fbusername; } ?>" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if($source=='fb'){ echo  $fbemail; } ?>" />
  <input type="file" name="file">
```

**3. Problem of Server side validation**

After server side validation i get

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="xyz xyz" />
<input type="text" name="email" value="xyz@abc.com xyz@abc.com" />
```

Comment: first of all you have an extra `"` near `echo  $fbemail; }" ?>" />` second while receiving data from fb trying printing them (and comment header once) and reply the output.

Comment: It was my mistake to add `"` while pasting  here, i have removed quote.

Comment: Ok and Have you tried printing results returned by fb ?

Comment: i'm able to retrieve data properly from fb. But during php validation HTTP request to server increased so session variable.
**If i  submit this  form 3 times it will show  one value 3 times.**